# Highlight Active Navigation Menu Item on Active page with CSS/JavaScript, No ids

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a pre-existing website, now this website need to work for partially visible people as well. The requirement is the Active Navigation menu Items should be highlighted on each active page.

The problem is that there is no id's for div and Ul/li tags for the navigation menu. 
If there were any ID's i could have created a css and called those to selected. Also I can not modify any HTML code of any page.

Could you please suggest any way to make this work out.

Looking forward for your answer.

Regards,
S

Comment: You don't need `id`s, but we need to see some code.

Comment: What are partially visible people and how can you see them? What websites do the use?

Comment: <div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Job Opportunities</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but i think you can handle this using element types and pseudo classes, like div li {...;} or div:nth-child(2){...;}

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution may be looping through all `<a>`s and comparing `window.location.href` to the value of their `href` if you're able to modify the Javascript.

Something like this should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/a7C8a/3/